# Validate form input depentent on another input

Tags: angularjs

I have a form where I validate an input field (Input A) dependent on another input field (Input B) which works nice so far. But when the content of Input B changes the validation of Input A does not recognize it and therefor still states the validation to be valid.

I made a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DtQstKpbNWPVUrfeLdX0) and I have some questions.

My link-function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, NgModelController) {
  NgModelController.$validators.invalid = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    var value = modelValue || viewValue;
    var validation = value <= ((scope.dependency / 100) * 50) && value >= ((scope.dependency / 100) * 10);

    console.log('bar', value);
    console.log('dependency', scope.dependency);
    console.log('validation', value, validation);

    return validation;
  };
  scope.$watch('dependency', function(newValue) {
    NgModelController.$setValidity('invalid', NgModelController.$validators.invalid(newValue));
console.log('new dependency', newValue, NgModelController.$validators.invalid(newValue), NgModelController.$error.invalid);
  });
}
```

1. Why does `NgModelController.$validators.invalid(newValue)` returns
   `true`, while `NgModelController.$error.invalid` returns `false`?
2. Why does my `$watch`-approach not work? Where is my mistake?

Comment: I would try to implement the check outside the form, I think in this case it should be easier to control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy:

```
scope.$watch('dependency', function(newValue) {
  // Force re-validation
  NgModelController.$validate(); 
});
```

See the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/828VkSBOs4rXJPCERqiC?p=preview).

Comment: The $setValidity should actually work too, but scanning the code I'm guessing you passed the wrong value to the function.

Comment: Nice that works pretty well but I still wonder why my solution does not work. It even returns a totally different value while the validation is the same. And `newValue` in this case must be the new number from "Foo" if I'm not wrong?

Comment: See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/canPpxzwyKCM3Bma7JRi?p=preview). You passed the value of `scope.dependency` instead of the value of the correct input.

Comment: Your plunker doesn't work. I just tried it by entering 50 into "Foo" then 50 into "Bar" and then changed "Foo" to 100. The validation should pass. But yes you are right I passed the wrong value. There must be something different in `$validate()` and `$setValidity()`

Comment: Updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/canPpxzwyKCM3Bma7JRi?p=preview) again. When a field is marked as invalid the modelValue is set to `undefined` by the `ngModelController`, which caused this issue.

Comment: Nice got it! Thank you very much :)